# uninstalling 'no-ip' from the terminal - how?

Tags: dns, dynamic-ip

I've tried to install the no-ip client but i couldn't complete the task via the terminal.
I want to know how to go back and delete all its files?
Thank you.

Comment: What did you try? This? https://docs.google.com/document/d/1BdHSzH_lVUxNXLL4OvGSfToT35E6dvQONBiJs2UWQZ0/edit

Comment: when i typed: sudo /usr/local/bin/noip2 -S
 i got the message: Can't locate configuration file /usr/local/etc/no-ip2.conf. (Try -c). Ending!

Answer (score 3):

There is a typo in the above command:

`/usr/local/bin/noip2 -C` (<kbd>-</kbd><kbd>C</kbd> (dash capital C) will create the default config file)

To uninstall if you aren't comfortable reviewing the changes made and reversing them, I suggest you [open a ticket](http://www.noip.com/ticket/) with no-ip.com.

[<sub>Source</sub>](http://www.noip.com/support/knowledgebase/installing-the-linux-dynamic-update-client-on-ubuntu/)